# Multiple queries in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I got some tag names from a table and then I need to search for each one in another one but i cannot do it with a **for** or something like that because the asynchronous way that sequelize works. Is there another form to solve this problem?

```
db.archivos.findAll({
    attributes: ['nombre','texto','related'],
        where: {
            nombre: nombre
        },
        raw: true
        }).then(function(archivos){
           if(archivos.length != 0){
              tags = archivos[0].related.split('/');
              cantTags = tags.length;


              for(i=0; i < cantTags; i++){
                db.tags.findAll({
                attributes: ['paginasRelacionadas'],
                    where: {
                        nombre: tags[i]
                    },
                    raw: true
                }).then(function(query){
                    related += paginasRelacionadas 
                });
              }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with `Promises` to resolve the async problem. Looking at the code you've posted, I imagine that something like this should do the trick (using ES2015):

```
db.archivos.findAll({
    attributes: ['nombre','texto','related'],
    where: {
        nombre: nombre
    },
    raw: true
}).then((archivos) =>
{
   const findTags => (related, tags, i=0) 
   {        
        const tag = tags[i];

        if(!tag)
            return Promise.resolve(related);

        return db.tags.findAll({
            attributes: ['paginasRelacionadas'],
            where: {
                nombre: tag
            },
            raw: true
        }).then(function(newRelated){
            related.push(...newRelated);
            return findTags(related, tags, ++i);
        });    
   };

   if(!archivos.length)
      return archivos;

   const tags = archivos[0].related.split('/');
   return findTags(archivos.related, tags).then((related) => 
   {
      archivos[0].related = related;
      return archivos;
   });

}).then((archivos) => 
{
    //do whatever you want with the archivos (here the 
    //first item will have the related properties with 
    //the new values)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@demarchisd is correct. Instead of iterating over the results synchronously you need to iterate with promises. Something like:

```
return db.Pormise.all(tags.map(function(tag)=>{
  db.tags.findAll({
  attributes: ['paginasRelacionadas'],
      where: {
          nombre: tags[i]
      },
      raw: true
  }).then(function(query) {
      related += query.paginasRelacionadas;
  });
}));
```